# Orchard NHibernate.Linq error

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I'm trying to add the Latest Twitter module to an Orchard application (hosted on Azure), however I'm getting the following error after registering it:

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate.Linq, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I unregister the Twitter module, the error doesn't occur, and I can't see any references to NHibernate.Linq in the module. The error is occurring in the DefaultContentQuery class.

Any idea what's going on?

**UPDATE**

Ahh, think I've found out. The module was referencing Orchard.Core and Orchard.Framework from within its own bin folder, so I changed it to reference the source projects. Presumably it was compiled with an older version.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Couldn't figure it out . . . This worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a bug (in referencing) within the CyberStride.Contacts and Mello.ImageGallery modules. They were referencing the Orchard dll's directly than the csproj files.

Quickly detected based off a simple grep command like ...

`find . -iname "*.csproj" | xargs grep -i "orchard*.dll"`

Wrong example:

```
<HintPath>..\..\bin\Orchard.Core.dll</HintPath>
```

Right example:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\Orchard.Core.csproj">
```